# How to represent classes with hierachical inheritance in a relationnal database

Tags: database

I have an abstract class "Person" which is inherited by a (non-abstract) class "Candidate", the latter has several subclasses : retained candidate (for interview), admitted candidate ... How can I represent that in database please?
Thank you

Comment: This is an incorrect use of inheritance. A person might play the role of a candidate but has not always been and always will be a candidate. Use composition. A person plays many roles, one of which can be candidate. And their status should not be a subtype either. Use a "status" column for that

Comment: Thank you for your answer , what you mean by composition please

Comment: I mean don't use inheritance :) You would want a one2many relationship between Person and PersonRoles

Comment: I didn't get it :/ can you give me an example of what PersonRoles should look like ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect use of inheritance. A person might play the role of a candidate but has not always been and always will be a candidate. Use composition. A person plays many roles, one of which can be candidate. They could later become an employee. And their status should not be a subtype either. Use a "status" column for that.

Something like this:

```
create table people (
  person_id int primary key,
  name text,
  ...
);

create table person_roles (
  person_id int references people(person_id),
  type text check (type in ('Candidate', '...') ),
  candidate_status text check (candidate_status in ('Retained','Admitted') ),

  primary key (person_id, type)
);
```

A correct use of inheritance would be Person extends AbstractLegalParty. Organization or Company would also extend AbstractLegalParty.

Comment: Why you've included type in the primary key? and btw you're right in this example I've given just an example, in my UML class diagram I've the following structure : Person (abstract class) inherited by Candidate,Staff and Admin, and candidate has two sub-classes : admitted and retained candidate, is this correct?

Comment: @saywow that allows a person to have multiple roles, but only one role of a given type

Comment: so I will represent in my UML a Person (abstract class) inherited by Candidate,Staff and Admin, and candidate is inherited by : admitted and retained candidate and when I want to represent that in the database I will do as you said, is that correct? that won't look like if person,member , candidat... have all the same hierarchical level ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are not a lot of data items, just make a single table with a type field. If there are lots of columns or variations, make tables for the variants and link them to a master table.

Comment: I would do that if there was only one hierarchical level (i.e. if there was for example only admitted and retained candidates inheriting from Person) but now I have two hierarchical levels I don't know how to do it